# In Java, is a while(true) behaving equally as an endless for-loop?

Tags: java, loops

Do the following loops behave the same in terms of speed & CPU usage:

**Loop 1**

```
while(true){}
```

**Loop 2**

```
for(int i = 0; i != -1 ; i++) {}
```

Are there any differences or is it basically the same code in 2 different expressions?

EDIT:

to specify:

Do the following loops behave the same in terms of speed & CPU usage in java?:

**Loop 1**

```
while(true){}
```

**Loop 2**

```
for(;;) {}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < -1 ; i++) {}` is not an infinite loop. `for(;;) {}` is.

Comment: The comparison is wrong. `i < -1` is not true even for the first iteration, so the second statement does nothing

Comment: If you'll modify your question to what @BackSlash wrote (which makes much more sense comparison-wise), then on my machine both compile to the same bytecode.

Comment: Ah so while(true) and for(;;) is behaving equally?

Comment: Second loop is not called even once, to achieve overflow change condition to, for example, `i != -1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two loops are not the same:

- The first loop will never stop
- The second loop will run for a long time, until `i` overflows, at which point the loop will exit.

Given that these two loops are not the same, the byte code, CPU usage, and speed for each would be different as well.

Comment: I would also add that any side effects of the loop statement would be run, and the bytecode would be different for each (hence different speed/CPU usage)

Answer (score 2):

It is similar but not identical. Keep in mind, the `i++` of the for loop is actually being executed each time through the loop, so it will be slower.

Also, the initialization of `i` to 0 is also something that does not happen with the while loop.

Finally, consider the fact that an integer may roll over from its greatest possible positive value to it's smallest possible negative value eventually.